# Automating file transferring from multiple source folders to one target folder

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I need to move different files from different folders to a new folder using a command line. The files share the same format `.asc`: for example, there are files `20file1.asc`, `20file2.asc` and `20file3.asc` existing in `folder1`, `folder2` and `folder3` respectively. 
I simply need to move the `.asc` from all folders to new folder which is `folder4`.
Each folder is named following a `yyyymmdd` scheme.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use simple script for that, like this one:

```
for x in {folder1,folder2,folder3}; do mv $x/*.asc folder4/; done
```

This script assumes you're in path that has folder1,folder2,folder3 in it.
You can tune it up to your needs.

For all folders in specific place you can do:

```
ls -1 >> file
for x in `cat file`; do mv $x/*.asc folder4/; done
```

But be aware, that `ls -1` will also contain files and if there are also files in that folder, you will get errors for these files, saying that path does not exist.

Comment: the number of folders I have is around 4000. the names are not as I provided, the names actually are dates in this format yyyymmdd. example: 20100415

Comment: you can do `ls -1 >> file` then ``for x in `cat file`; do mv...``

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all source folders are in the same directory path, you can use the following bash script:

```
ls -1 >> sources
for x in `cat sources`; do mv $x/*.asc target/; done
rm sources
```

Save it in your main folder with some `name.sh`, then run

```
$ sh name.sh
```

to get the job done automatically.